# Mapping a nullable decimal with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5

I have a `nullable decimal field` in my table and when I generate an `edmx model`, the `nullable decimal field` does not show up in the `entity`.  Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Entity Framework 3.5 does not support MySql unsigned types.  After changing it to signed, it was added to the model.  I am not sure if this has been fixed in future versions of EF and if it only applies to unsigned decimals.